# The name "request" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, wpf, webrequest

I am trying to do a task using WebRequest, but it does not allow me to access it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frXbS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value in a function or directly during initialization

```
public WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"https://yandex.ru/pogoda");
```

Would you please share your code next time as text and not as screenshot